# Hibernate does not return newly inserted data

Tags: hibernate, caching

I'm using an open source application for e-commerce. Application uses hibernate 3. When I add new products manually to the database, hibernate won't query them. Actually it doesn't show new products at the client panel, although it shows them at the admin panel. I can see new products are saved through admin panel, but they are not visible at the client panel. But, when i click save button to save the product on the admin panel (which invokes hibernate to update, event though nothing changes) product get listed at the client panel. Sounds to me like a problem with hibernate caching or something. I have disabled all the caching and lowered connection isolation level persistence.xml (in the e-commerce applicaton) like following:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/> 
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="1"></property>
```

Comment: Your application probably has its own cache.